# Reassigning a value to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I feel like I must be missing something really obvious here. I'm grabbing the text from within a div and using an if statement to reassign the value of the variable to "javascript" if it's "HTML", but this doesn't seem to be working at all.

Could somebody help me with this?

```js
var currentChoice = $('#contentSelector').text();      
var newChoice = currentChoice;
if (currentChoice == 'HTML') {
  currentChoice = 'Javascript';
};
alert(currentChoice);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentSelector"> HTML </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is in your alert box when it pops up?

Comment: Also, what is it before the if statement?

Comment: HTML before and after

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are spaces around 'HTML' so it's likely not matching. " HTML " is different than "HTML".

Do this and it works `$.trim($('#contentSelector').text());`

Comment: This is correct, thanks Arthur, didnt realise it wouldnt match if there is white space. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have spaces either side of the `HTML` text value of the element. You can use `trim()` to remove these before testing the value in the `if` statement:

```
var currentChoice = $('#contentSelector').text().trim();
```

Comment: This works as long as you don't need to support IE < 9

Answer (score 0):

If you already use jquery, why not:

```
var $currentChoice = $('#contentSelector')      
if ($currentChoice.text().toString() == "HTML"){
    $currentChoice.text('Javascript');
};
```